# assign a cell to a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have the following matrix :

```
 adj =     O1   O2    O3    O4    S1    S2    S3    S4    S5

 O1        0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
 O2        0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
 O3        0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
 O4        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
 S1        0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 S2        0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 S3        0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 S4        0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 S5        0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

I have a cellarray nodeNames that contains the labels of the lines and columns of my matrix so :

```
nodeNames = {O1 O2 O3 O4 S1 S2 S3 S4 S5}
```

I want to do the following: browse the matirce adj in the lines from the nodes `S` (i = 5: 9) and for the columns the nodes `O` (j = 1; 4) if `adj (i, j) = 1` then get the label of the node `Oj` from `nodeNames` and put it in the cell `w {i}` of a new cellarray that we will name `w`.
so I want to have the following:

```
w{1}={O3}.
w{2}={O2}.
w{3}={O2 O3}.
w{4}={O2 O4}.
w{5}={O4}.
```

I have tried to do that but I get an empty cellarray in my result :

```
for i=5 : 9
    k=1;
    for j=1:4
        if adj(i,j)==1;
            w{i}{k}=nodeNames{j};
        end
        k=k+1;
    end
end
```

I know that the problem is in the assignment to the cellarray `w` but can't get the right one , Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nodeNames` or `nodNames`, also your k=k+1 must be in the if-statement.

```
adj=[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0;0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0;0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0;0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1;0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0;0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0;0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]==1;
nodeNames = {'O1','O2','O3','O4','S1','S2','S3','S4','S5'};
w={};
for i = 5:9
    k=1;
    for j=1:4
        if adj(i,j)
        w{i-4,k}=nodeNames{j};
        k=k+1;
        end
    end
end
```

Result:

```
w =

  5×2 cell array

    'O3'      []
    'O2'      []
    'O2'    'O3'
    'O2'    'O4'
    'O4'      []
```